# How to call member function of class in another m file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, class, oop

How can call class function,and initialize object of class in another file.m ,
when calling from command window its work but I wanna call function from m file.

i have folder:@myClassName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you declare your object in a function you must return an output argumant of your function you can see the result in workspace

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it works from the command window, then most likely the problem is the path. The folder containing the class-folder @myClassName must be in the path (see function `addpath`). From the other file you just need to:

```
my_instance = myClassName(...) % ... represent the inputs to your constructor.
my_instance.MyFunction(...);
```